# How To Remove Punctuation In String Using List Comprehension?

Tags: python, arrays, list, list-comprehension

How To Remove Punctuation In String Using List Comprehension ?

```
punctuations="!@#$%^&*()_-=+:;{}[]<>,.?/\''"
analyzed=""
text="This is ;;;; $# @#%@$ A String <>?::"
```

I Know How To Do It With For Loop :

```
for i in text:
     if i not in punctuations:
          analyzed+=i
print(analyzed)
```

But How Can I Do It Using List Comprehension ?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: i tried : print([analyzed+=i for i in punctuations if i in text])

Comment: Use a list comprehension with a conditional, and pass it as an argument to `''.join()`

Comment: You have it backwards. `for i in text if i not in punctuations`

Comment: what's do you print the `i`? don't you want the `analyzed` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generator, and pass it as an argument to `join()` to convert the result back into a string.

```
analyzed = ''.join(c for c in text if c not in punctuations)
print(analyzed)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
punctuations="!@#$%^&*()_-=+:;{}[]<>,.?/\''"
analyzed=""
text="This is ;;;; $# @#%@$ A String <>?::"
```

**Try this**:

```
>>[c for c in text if c not in punctuations]
```

You will get:

```
['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'A', ' ', 'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ']
```

If you want it as a single string, just join all of them.

```
>>''.join(c for c in text if c not in punctuations)
'This is    A String '
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert your punctuations and strings into a list and then separate it, as follows:

```
import string

list = ["!", "This","@", "#", "$", "is", "%", "a", "^", "&", "list", "*", "(", ")"]

list2 = [idx for idx in list if not any(punc in idx for punc in string.punctuation)]

print(str(list2))
```

Output:

```
['This', 'is', 'a', 'list']
```